# Make a UserCOntrol on a Page the same size as the MainWindow in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application.  It consists of:

1. A MainWindow which loads a Page which contains a UserControl.
2. The UserControl is simply a MediaElement with play/pause controls etc.

Here is the XAML for the UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="InstallerToolkit.UserControls.UserControlVideoPlayer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="464">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Black">
    <StackPanel  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <MediaElement Name="MediaElement" MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop"/>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="DarkGray"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="/Images/control_play.png" MouseDown="OnMouseDownPlayMedia" Margin="5" />
            <Image Source="/images/control_pause.png" MouseDown="OnMouseDownPauseMedia" Margin="5" />
            <Image Source="/images/control_stop.png" MouseDown="OnMouseDownStopMedia" Margin="5" />
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="5"  VerticalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="Seek To"/></TextBlock>
            <Slider x:Name="timelineSlider" Thumb.DragStarted="DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="DragCompleted" Margin="5" ValueChanged="SeekToMediaPosition"  Width="70"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblProgressStatus" Margin="5"><Run Text="00:00"/></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblSepatator" Margin="5"><Run Text="/"/></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblTotalLength" Margin="5" RenderTransformOrigin="3.607,0.455"><Run Text="00:00"/></TextBlock>
            <Image Source="/images/control_stop.png" Margin="145,0,0,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here is the positon of my UserControl normally:

[image]

I have added a button to the UserControl to try and make it go the full size of the MainWindow.
WHen I click the fullscreen button I have an event on my page which does the following:

```
    private void VideoPlayer_FullScreenSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var parentWindowWidth = ((System.Windows.Controls.Panel)(Application.Current.MainWindow.Content)).ActualWidth;
        var parentWindowHeight = ((System.Windows.Controls.Panel)(Application.Current.MainWindow.Content)).ActualHeight;

        Thickness margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
        VideoPlayer.Margin = margin;
        VideoPlayer.Width = parentWindowWidth;
        VideoPlayer.Height = parentWindowHeight;

    }
```

When I do this I see the VideoPlayer appearing larger like so:

[image]

Note how it is the size of my Page but not the MainWindow which I want ot to be.

So then I have added an event to my Page which triggers a function in my MainWindow that tries to grab the MediaElement from my Page and make it fullscreen.  But I dont know how to grab my UserCOntrol from here and make it the size I need.

How can I do this??

Answer (score 3):

You are grabbing window content height and width which is page instead and not your window.

Instead of

```
var parentWindowWidth = ((System.Windows.Controls.Panel)
                   (Application.Current.MainWindow.Content)).ActualWidth;
var parentWindowHeight = ((System.Windows.Controls.Panel)
                   (Application.Current.MainWindow.Content)).ActualHeight;
```

you should use MainWindow height and width:

```
var parentWindowWidth = Application.Current.MainWindow.ActualWidth;
var parentWindowHeight = Application.Current.MainWindow.ActualHeight;
```

Comment: Both are giving me the same parameters (width=1200, height=750).  These are the actual parameters of my main application window.  WHny is it not going fullscreen??

Comment: You mentioned in question `Note how it is the size of my Page but not the MainWindow which I want it to be.` Don't you want that to be size of MainWindow?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes I want the usercontrol (VideoPlayer) to be the same size as my MainWindow which is 1200x750.

Comment: So you are getting it 1200X750. What's an issue then?

Comment: Yes I'm setting it to that size but its not going to that size.  The actual UserControl is not going to the size of 1200x750. Its somehow being restricted to the size of the Page that its in(The page is 1050x525)

Answer (score 0):

I found another way around this problem.

I created a new Window and made its size to be 1200x750.  On this window I placed my VideoPlayer Usercontrol and made it full screen.

Thwn when I click the 'fullscreen' button I simply launch this new window and pass it the current position of my video to make it appear like its continuing playing.  When this window is closed I pass the current video positon back again and continue from there.

```
    private void VideoPlayer_FullScreenSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoPlayer.Pause();

        //Get the current media position
        _currentMediaPosition = VideoPlayer.CurrentPosition;

        VideoFullScreenWindow fullScreenVideo = new VideoFullScreenWindow(_currentMediaPosition, _videoFile);

        fullScreenVideo.ShowDialog();

        TimeSpan pos = fullScreenVideo.Position;

        VideoPlayer.SeekToPosition(pos);
        VideoPlayer.Play();


    }
```