# MouseDown event on new Window does not DragMove MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that I have removed the border and default controls by doing the following:

```
WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"
```

Now I added  a MouseDown handler **MouseDown="Window_MouseDown"** and added the following code to allow me to move my Window around:

```
    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
                DragMove();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
```

But now I have a UserControl that I want to resize to the full size of my Application so to achieve this I created a new Window that is the same size as my MainWindow and placed the UserControl onto it.  I create this new Window and set its parent to be my main application like so:

```
    public MyFullScreenWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;

    }
```

I launch this window like so:

```
            MyFullScreenWindow fullScreen = new MyFullScreenWindow();
            fullScreenVideo.ShowDialog();
```

My problem is that I want to still move my whole application around whenever the user clicks and moves this new window.  To achieve this I have added an Event to MyFullScreenWindow:

```
public partial class MyFullScreenWindow: Window
{
    static public event EventHandler MouseDownEvent;


    public MyFullScreenWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
    }



    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseDownEvent != null)
        {
            MouseDownEvent(sender, e);
        }
    }
 }
```

And I handle this event in my MainWindow like so:

```
 MyFullScreenWindow.MouseDownEvent += new EventHandler(MyFullScreenMouseDownHandler);

    private void MyFullScreenMouseDownHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DragMove();

    }
```

But when I click and drag I see that the event is fired off but my whole application does not move like it should.  Why is this??

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following function code only

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        // Begin dragging the window
        this.DragMove();
    }
```

move your window where ever you want.

Comment: Yes this moves MyFullScreenWindow but it does not move the MainWindow in the background

Comment: try two actions first try to assign `WindowOwner` to this windows and write the same code for `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context of your problem, but why would you create a new window, "place" it inside the parent one? You can use controls without creating a new window.

It's possible that you are doing this because you need AllowTransparency=false functionality, while showing it in AllowTransparency=true window. (I had this case when working with DirectShow). If you're doing this for custom window chrome, then don't use AllowTransparency - it decreases performance greatly. It's creating picture of every frame and disables GPU acceleration, after all! Instead, you can adapt to CustomChromeWindow project(found on Internets).

Note that you can enable the main window so that it would process messages from underlying window:

```
 public class WindowSecond : Window
    {
        public WindowSecond()
        {
            Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            MouseDown += delegate
                {
                    // maybe cache it.
                    IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(Owner).Handle;

                    EnableWindow(handle, true);
                    Application.Current.MainWindow.DragMove();
                    EnableWindow(handle, false);
                };
        }

        [DllImport("user32")]
        internal static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hwnd, bool bEnable);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Please see this link for the context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663921/make-a-usercontrol-on-a-page-the-same-size-as-the-mainwindow-in-wpf When I try Your solution and when I move the mouse it does indeed move my MainWindow in the background but the new fullscreen window stays in the same place.  I want to move them both together (So my application appears as one)#

Comment: I've done something similiar. I don't understand though why do you need those DragMoves etc. If window is full screen, it will have NoResize & Maximized flags, which means that you can't move fullscreen. This is how full screens work after all.

Comment: Remember you can always craft your own DragMove(). All you have to do: capture mouse & coordinates on MouseDownEvent. On MouseMoveEvent, you manipulate windows Left&Top properties, Left+=mouseClickOrigin.X-curentMouseOrigin.X;. YOu will have to release mouse capture on MouseReleasedEvent

Comment: My MyFullScreenWindow window is not fullscreen, it is the same size as the MainWindow (The main application) so when MyFullScreenWindow is on top I want to move both MyFullScreenWindow and MainWindow. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah. Then you're not going the right way on this. I've seen way too many examples of people trying to do this "synchronized" windows tricks that I can honestly say; it's not going to work. There are way too many cases, and even all the cases handled, they will go out of sync. Try to get your original solution to work. Remember that you can disconnect your VideoElement from VisualTree and insert it into Window, temporarily. If the VideoElement is in Grid,you can do YourGrid.Children.Remove(YOURVIDEO_ELEMENT)